# Css fade out when done with hover

Tags: html, css, animation, text, fade

I am fairly new to css and html, so i think this might be a simple question.

I have a block that darkens when hovering on it with text in front of it
but i cant get a fade out animation.

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8U6p/)

```
.block1 {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    background-color:red;
}

.block1text {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    font-family:Raleway;
    font-weight:700;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25pt;
    color:#eee;
    line-height:320px;
    letter-spacing:2px; 
    position:absolute;
}

.block1:hover > .overlay {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;

    -o-transition:.4s ease;
    -ms-transition:.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition:.4s ease;
    transition:.4s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your CSS transition is only applying when block1 is in its hover state. I got it to work by giving the overlay some basic styles (including the transition) and only changing a couple of properties on block1 hover. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9K7EP/).

Think of it as "at all times, I want any property changes to the overlay element to have a 0.4s transition effect".

Here are the CSS changes:

```
.block1 > .overlay {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;

    -o-transition:.4s ease;
    -ms-transition:.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition:.4s ease;
    transition:.4s;    
}

.block1:hover > .overlay {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```